# How can I make an element fit to fill the right part of the window?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html page:

```
<body>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

And the css is like this:

```
#div1{
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  top: 0;
  left 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#div2{
  width: auto;
  height: 160px;
  top 0;
  left: 160px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

How can I make `div2` stretch to fill the right part of the window while the window is being resized. That means the width of `div1` will always be **160px**, but the width of `div2` will fit the rest of the window. `auto` didn't work here if there is no content in `div2`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `right:0` to your `#div2` styles.

Comment: Bravo! That works! Could you explain why putting right:0 solves this issue?

Comment: Because it's defined in CSS 2.1 that way :-) http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

Answer (score 1):

elements with `position: absolute` are outside the document flow therefore can't "wrap" in `width`.

use `float` and `margin`:

```
#div1{
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  float: left;
}

#div2{
  margin-left: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6nFDS/

Comment: Does it mean that div1 is on the top of div2? If so, if height of div1 is small than div2, part of background of div2 will appear below div1.

Comment: This works without "position: absolute" for div2. If I put "position:absolute", div2 disappear.

Comment: Is it a best practice of css to try to avoid position:absolute?

Comment: if you check my css you will see that there is no `position: absolute;` - and it works the way you wanted it. Whoever downvoted should comment why because it makes no sense. It is not best practice to avoid `position: absolute` but it is best used the right way - from your code there is no need for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And what if I need a div3 right below div1 and of the same width of div1, and another div4 right below div2 and of the same width of div2? I'm not sure whether I can do that without "position: absolute". Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not quite sure if this is what you want, but you could use `width: 100%;`:

```
width: 100%;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NcdqM/)

Comment: 100% doesn't work. I think width: 100% means 100% of it's parent. However, the width of div2 is supposed to be the width of body - 160px. If 100% is used here, div2 will flow out the body by 160px.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete toturial of CSS layout here :
http://learnlayout.com/

You can use :

```
 display:inline-block
```